# Archive artifacts by list from a file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

My build job produces various artifacts, they are based on parameters but not directly computable from them. The artifacts are undetermined until the build steps complete. 
Upon build steps completion, the newly created artifacts' file names are located in the designated file (known in advance)

**I want to archive the artifacts by specifying their file names in that file. How can I do it?**

P.S. From what I know, the "Archive the artifacts" step specs are similar to *includes* attribute of [Ant fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html). I need something like *includesfile*.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the file with the `readFile` step, and convert it to the format expected by `archiveArtifacts` (comma-separated String of items). E.g.:

```
String artifacts = readFile(file: 'artifacts.txt').split('\n').join(',')
archiveArtifacts artifacts
```

Comment: This solution applies only when using the pipeline project.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Your question is tagged with jenkins-pipeline though, so I assumed that was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to workaround the issue:

1. Add post-build script step (before archiving artifacts). In it: iterate over file names in the file, copy each to the designated (empty) folder
2. Configure the Archive artifacts step to take all files from that designated folder.